# Convert string to pdf

Tags: apex

How to convert string to pfd in Apex, I am sending pdf from SFDC to other application through REST Api, Pdf is not getting open in destination application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visualforce for this, setting [apex:page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) `renderAs="pdf"` or instead using [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm) `getContentAsPDF`. Either of these ensures that the data is the [PDF file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format). Adjust the CSS for the page to get the styling you want - see e.g. [Creating Professional PDF Documents with CSS and Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce).

You will then need to encode that data as required by the "other application" and set the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

renderAs = "pdf" will not work in this scenario since i need to convert string to pdf in apex class.

Below is worked for me.

```
blob b = blob.toPDF(notebody);
```

Thanks,
Anil Kumar

Comment: Actually, you can use a VF page to render a PDF in Apex.  You'd simply use the PageReference / getContentAsPDF method: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm